# Arduino: 1.8.14 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

Tags: arduino

Arduino: 1.8.14 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware -hardware C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -tools C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\tools-builder -tools C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\libraries -libraries C:\Users\hp\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -vid-pid=0000_0000 -ide-version=10814 -build-path C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_864642 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7.path=C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\hp\Desktop\2nd semister\embeded technology and iot\sketch_jun10_2nd_one\sketch_jun10_2nd_one.ino

C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware -hardware C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -tools C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\tools-builder -tools C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\tools\avr -tools C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages -built-in-libraries C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\libraries -libraries C:\Users\hp\Documents\Arduino\libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -vid-pid=0000_0000 -ide-version=10814 -build-path C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372 -warnings=none -build-cache C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_864642 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7 -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc-7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7.path=C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA-1.3.0.path=C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\tools\avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude-6.3.0-arduino17.path=C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\tools\avr -verbose C:\Users\hp\Desktop\2nd semister\embeded technology and iot\sketch_jun10_2nd_one\sketch_jun10_2nd_one.ino

Using board 'uno' from platform in folder: C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr

Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr

Detecting libraries used...

"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10814 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\sketch\sketch_jun10_2nd_one.ino.cpp" -o nul

Generating function prototypes...

"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10814 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\sketch\sketch_jun10_2nd_one.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"

"C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\tools-builder\ctags\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"

Compiling sketch...

"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-error=narrowing -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10814 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\sketch\sketch_jun10_2nd_one.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\sketch\sketch_jun10_2nd_one.ino.cpp.o"

Compiling libraries...

Compiling core...

"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -x assembler-with-cpp -flto -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10814 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_pulse.S" -o "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\core\wiring_pulse.S.o"

"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10814 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\WInterrupts.c" -o "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\core\WInterrupts.c.o"

"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10814 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\hooks.c" -o "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\core\hooks.c.o"

"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10814 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_pulse.c" -o "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\core\wiring_pulse.c.o"

"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10814 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_analog.c" -o "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\core\wiring_analog.c.o"

"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10814 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_shift.c" -o "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\core\wiring_shift.c.o"

"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10814 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring.c" -o "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\core\wiring.c.o"

"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7/bin/avr-gcc" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10814 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino" "-IC:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard" "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\arduino-1.8.14\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino\wiring_digital.c" -o "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_879372\core\wiring_digital.c.o"

cc1.exe: fatal error: can't open 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\ccy8IlXP.s' for writing: Permission denied

compilation terminated.

exit status 1

Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.

Comment: `Permission denied` ==> pretty much all you need to know, I think.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm the port exists enter the following from the root directory.

```
ls /dev/ttyACM0
```

To set read/write permissions, enter the following

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0
```

Comment: OP says they are on Windows 10, not Linux or Mac. Your answer applies only to Mac or Linux I think.

Comment: Nope, windows 10 (newer versions) has "Windows 10 ioT Dashboard", from there you can enter into powershell where he can enter these commands.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but assuming the use of Arduino IDE? Furthermore seems to be permission based error

> cc1.exe: fatal error: can't open 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\ccy8IlXP.s' for writing: Permission denied

Perhaps try running Arduino IDE as admin. In windows right click Arduino IDE -> Run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the [link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux) steps

Download the Arduino Software (IDE). lscpu will tell you if 32 or 64 bits. If unsure, use 32 bits.
Extract the package (from terminal tar -xvf arduino-1.8.2-linux64.tar.xz).
Run the installation script (./install.sh).